# Attach a process for debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am hosting an application on IIS but application gets up very late when I restart IIS. So I want to debug it at the begining of the application start but I cannot attach a process if the application doesnt start. so what is the proper way to debug an application that is host on IIS when the application firstly begin ?

Comment: I don't think there is way to debug when application on IIS.

Comment: I don't understand 'cannot attach a process if the application doesnt start'..followed by..'debug an application that is host on IIS when the application begin first'..is the application starting or not?  I'm assuming you mean that you can not attach the debugger to the process until it has started, but this is a problem because you want to debug application start.

Comment: Let me explain it step by step. If I dont start an application that is host on IIS, I cannot attach it. So I couldnt see what is happening when the application starts at the first time. The second way that is advised by @competent_tech seems to be working fine but I want to see alternative ways if more than these.

Comment: @Shree Khanal, are you sure about that?

Comment: Does anyone know what this author is talking about?  Why is he calling a web application, an "application that is host on", even his description make no sense.

Comment: @Ramhound At least two of them know what I am talking about.

Comment: @Ramhound That is why I passed the question over. Kaplan we all do it once in a while but I would make sure it makes sense before posting it :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about put a `Debugger.Launch()` in `Global.Application_Start`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to select Start Debugging from the Debug menu in Visual Studio.

Another way is to add a `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail("test")` to the location within the code that you want to break, then reset IIS and attach to IIS from VS.