# How to debug a .NET web service initialization code in VS 2010?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

Context: .NET web service deployed on local IIS in XP. VS 2010 used to debug the webservice code.

Problem:
I am familiar with debugging a hosted webservice by attaching VS to ASP.NET worker process. This approach works if the portion of code being debugged is not the initialization code such as constructors within webservice. When the ASP NET worker process is created, it calls the constructors in the webservice. So by the time we attach to ASP NET worker process from VS, the constructors have already been invoked and therefore not possible to debug.

How do i attach to the ASPNET process and debug the webservice even before it reaches the constructors within the webservice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536751/attach-a-process-for-debugging-in-visual-studio).
You can insert a

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

instruction in the web service constructor to be prompted for a debugger to attach. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx).

[image]

Comment: Will that work with a service? I thought it needs UI permissions to be able to do that and services don't have UI access.

Comment: Just tried it and it works fine, although I'm not sure if there are restrictions depending on what user IIS is running under and on what OS/IIS versions.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip, it will help me out too.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best option, but it was the only solution I was able to find when I had a similar problem. Put a `Thread.Sleep(xxxx)` in your constructor and try and race to beat the clock and get attached before it is finished initializing. You need to be careful not to set the sleep too high as the service could get stopped if it is not done initializing under a certain number of seconds. (it is also a pain when it decides to kill the service on you before you have finished stepping through the initialization function because it did not return quick enough.)